# Three integral expressions for integer values of $\zeta(s)$. Could these be further reduced to known integrals?

Tags: nt.number-theory, integration, riemann-zeta-function

In [this MSE-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3668013/could-this-integral-expression-for-zeta3-be-simplified-any-further) I've asked about three, similarly shaped, integrals for integer vales of $\zeta(s)$ that I found numerically:

$$\zeta \left( 3 \right) =\frac12{\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x}\big(\zeta(2)-{\it Li_2} \left(1-x\right)\big) \,{\rm d}x} \tag{1}$$

$$\zeta \left( 4 \right) =\frac{4}{5}{\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x}\big(\zeta(3)-{\it Li_3} \left(1-x\right)\big) \,{\rm d}x} \tag{2}$$

$$\zeta \left( 5 \right) =\frac12{\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x}\big(\zeta(2)-{\it Li_2} \left(1-x\right)\big)^2 \,{\rm d}x} \tag{3}$$

**ADDED:** found one more:

$$\zeta \left( 3 \right) = \frac32 - \frac14{\int_{0}^{1} \big(\zeta(2)-{\it Li_2} \left(1-x\right)\big)^2 \,{\rm d}x} \tag{4}$$

where ${\it Li_n}(z)$  [is the PolyLogarithm](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html).

I have not found any similar expressions at other integer values.

The answer to the MSE-question helped reducing the integral for $\zeta(3)$ to a known integral, however still curious whether the other two could be reduced to something known as well.

Comment: Again indicate the series corresponding to the integral

Comment: "a known integral" --- if Mathematica [knows the integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B%28Zeta%5B3%5D+-+PolyLog%5B3%2C+1+-+x%5D%29%2Fx%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+1%7D%5D), does that count?

Comment: @Carlo Beenhakker, yes, that counts since Mathematica also yields the indefinite integral for the $\zeta(4)$-case. One down; how about the integral for $\zeta(5)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These identities, and many more, follow from a theorem in [Integrals of polylogarithmic functions, recurrence relations, and associated Euler sums](https://carma.newcastle.edu.au/resources/jon/Preprints/Papers/ArXiv/Zeta21/polylog.pdf),

[image]

For example,

[image]

[image]
[image]

There are also variations with $\log x$ factor, such as

[image]

Comment: Thanks Carlo. This will solve the $\zeta(5)$ case in equation (3)! I had actually just found (numerically) this simple equation for integers $n \ge 2$: 

$${\int_{0}^{1} \zeta(n)-{\it Li_n} \left(1-x\right) \,{\rm d}x} = (-1)^n \left(1-\sum_{k=2}^{n-1} (-1)^k\,\zeta(k) \right)$$